# Align Quote to right

Tags: horizontal-alignment, quoting, epigraphs

I want to align

```
\begin{quote}
  Text
  Author (\cite{Source})
\end{quote}
```

to the right side of the paper. How can I do this?

Comment: What exactly do you want? You want the right margin of the quote environment to be the same as the right margin of the surrounding text?

Comment: look for "epigraph" on ctan.  also, this has been addressed a few times in [http://tug.org/tugboat](tugboat); again, search for "epigraph".  (i'm not where i can easily do the search effectively at the moment.)

Answer (score 6):

redefine the `quote` environment

```
\renewenvironment{quote}
  {\begin{trivlist} \setlength\leftskip{2cm} \setlength\rightskip{0pt}
   \item\relax}
  {\end{trivlist}}
```

or define a new `Quote` environment with the same code

Answer (score 3):

Staying close to the definition of the `quote` environment (in the `article` class file), I'd recommend the following redefinition in order to achieve what (I think) you're looking for:

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{quote}
     {\list{}{
        \if@twocolumn
           \leftmargin {3em} 
               \else
                \leftmargin {5em}
               \fi
               \rightmargin 0pt}%
            \item\relax}
    {\endlist}
\makeatother
```

Remark: If you're sure you're only going to use this code in a single-column environment, you can simplify the code considerably (note, in particular, that you no longer need the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` commands):

```
\newenvironment{quote}
     {\list{}{\leftmargin {5em}
              \rightmargin{0pt}}%
       \item\relax}
     {\endlist}
```

Of course, depending on your preferences, you may prefer to increase or decrease the amount of left-hand indentation; the `5em` amount is simply an example (obtained by doubling the amount set in the article.cls file).

Answer (score 0):

Add to your preamble:

```
    \makeatletter{}
\g@addto@macro\quote\flushright
\makeatother
```

And quotes will be printed flushright.

Comment: Is this a (correct) solution for the OP's problem? The way I understand the question, the OP wants to have the whole quote environment shifted to the right, while preserving full justification rather than getting right-justification)of the text inside the quote. I agree with @barbarabeeton's comment that he should use the `epigraph` environment for this job.

Comment: @Mico: Maybe you are right, maybe me. Let's hope OP will specify his question.